# Poco x3 cannot transfer files to PC?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android, file-transfer

I'm on a Poco x3 NFC, and I tried transferring files to PC via USB cable.  The phone charges in USB 3.0 ports but in USB 2.0 ports, it just blinks the LED once, shows the charging screen briefly, then stops charging.

I used multiple computers and ports on each one: the thing won't do file transfer!

Comment: Sounds like USB 2.0 doesn’t provide enough power to charge the device.  You should stick to using USB 3.0 ports. However, your question title does not match your question body.  You should [edit] your question to resolve that conflict

Comment: Test different USB cables. When connect to a PC make sure the Android phone is in file transfer mode: there is notification added when you connect the phone to your PC that can be used to switch the USB mode.

Comment: @Ramhound That is mentioned in the answer.  I didn't realize my answer was in draft mode.  Sorry.  I'll delete this comment later.

Comment: @Robert Those notifications do not appear on this phone unless the drivers are installed, and the phone does not install the drivers--they must be installed manually via Hardware Manager.  The phone is not released in the US, yet, and their online support team said that people care less about transferring files to PC in China.  Hmm....

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Source:

This solution is tested by me and works: https://www.androidusbdrivers.com/xiaomi-poco-x3-nfc-usb-drivers/.  I am adding a tutorial because I want to be sure the info is permanent.

### File locations:

If the files become unavailable, I can upload them to a new location.  I will keep them permanently in my offline drivers log.

Flashing Firmware Driver: https://www.androidusbdrivers.com/xiaomi-poco-x3-nfc-usb-drivers/ first link (meta won't allow bitly addresses).
USB Driver: https://www.androidusbdrivers.com/go/latest-usb-driver-windows/
Fastboot and ADB Driver: https://www.androidusbdrivers.com/go/adb-fastboot-drivers/

I installed all of these.

### Tutorial:

You must install the USB_Driver to transfer files.
You may only transfer files over USB 3.0 or greater (blue port on the computer or red, not black).

How to install in Windows 10: go to Start, type Device Manager, open Device Manager.

Click on Desktop (first line).  Only afterwards, click "Action" in the drop-down menu then click Add Legacy Hardware.

Install Hardware that I manually select.

Show all.

Have Disk.  Browse.  Drivers/USB_Driver/android_winusb.inf.  Open.  OK.

Next.  Etc. etc. etc.

You can repeat these steps if you want to change the OS/ROM on the device and add the second and third component of the .inf file.  The bootloader is necessary for the flash/unlock tool to work.  Not sure what the composite driver is for.

You may need to log out or restart your computer.  ***IMPORTANT:*** USB 2.0 ports do not transfer enough power to allow data transfer: please, only plug your phone into USB 3.0 or greater ports to prevent power shorts.  I cannot say with great confidence that a short can occur; however, power shortages are the leading cause of electronics failures and until I can confirm otherwise, I will avoid "slow-charging-mode", personally.  The blue ports are 3.0 the red ports are 3.1.  You can also use USB-C to USB-C for data transfer, and you can also put your files on a micro-SD card via the file manager on your phone and then put the microSD card into your computer.  My **OTG drives are not compatible with this model of cell phone**.